# show overflow-x scrollbar after some delay

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

i am using **overflow-x in my modal dialog box** but i want that scroll bar to be appear after modal dialog box load. here i am just writing a code snippet to better understand. is there any way to do it

HTML File

```
<div class="md-modal">
<div class="md-content">
Modal Dialog Content
</div>
</div>

CSS File

.md-modal
{
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Use jQuery to add the overflow-x css property after some delay.

Comment: @crunch: i know that it is possible using js but how...i am new to web designing

Comment: See my answer. I didn't have an opportunity to test it, but hopefully it gives you an idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.md-modal').css('overflow-x', 'scroll');
}, 5000); // 5 seconds
</script>
```

Make sure you include jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's not working. if you want to show what code i am using then you can see it on this link: tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/.   i am using 3D Slit Effect